# Hardware ISP and v4l2

Tags: linux, v4l2, tegra

I'm new to Linux.

My doubt is regarding v4l2 driver supporting existing ISP harware in Jetson TX1.

I would like to know whether basic v4l2 implementation in Linux provides an interface to send data to ISP(hardware module) or not?

If not provided, is it possible to modify the v4l2 implementation so that it does not bypass ISP.

And also, I would like to know, how the data flows from an image sensor to system memory through v4l2( if possible can i get sources for block diagram representing this data flow)

Please help me...